# Selenium - WebElement object has no attribute 'sendKeys'

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to enter text into an input field using selenium but it's giving an error. The code is:

```
input1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-dialog dialog"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input')
input1.sendKeys("myusername")
```

However it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Bradley Jo\Desktop\Project\app.py", line 14, in 
<module>
input1.sendKeys("hello")
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'sendKeys'
```

Answer (score 6):

the method is not sendKeys. It is send_keys.

```
input1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-dialog dialog"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input')
input1.send_keys("myusername")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use actions instead of direct typing in input field.
Please use the below portion of code

```
input1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="login-dialog dialog"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[1]/input')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(input1).send_keys("myusername").perform()
```

If the browser is your driver then change driver with browser.